# Rotate around point whilst maintaining forward facing direction

Tags: vectors, 3d, rotations

I have a stationary point, the origin (O) at (0, 0, 0) and a moving Point (P) that I wish to have rotating around O with a fixed radius (d). However, rather than just rotating around I always want to ensure that point P is facing in the direction of travel.

Imagine tying a rope to yourself, and the other end to a pole in your garden. If you were to run you would be running in a circle around the pole, but would be facing in your (every changing) direction of travel.

Can anyone advise me either of the algorithms required, or at least some better search terms, since "Rotate Around a Point" doesn't provide what I'm looking for.

[Visual Example of above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7VPF.jpg)

Comment: If this is a 3D problem then it is not enough that you say "rotate around the origin". In what plane?

Comment: @zoli Apologies - I want to rotate around the Y axis, where positive Y is "up"

Answer (score 1):

A parametric equation of the path is $(d\cos(\alpha),0,d\sin(\alpha) ); \,\, 0\le\alpha<2\pi$. Still, a point does not have a direction, so you need to apply a vector. This vector will have to be parallel to the tangent to the circle. For example the short vector $$\varepsilon(-\sin(\alpha),0,\cos(\alpha))$$ points
in the direction of the movement if $\alpha$ moves from $0$ to $2\pi$ ($\varepsilon>0).$

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to imagine a point "facing in the direction of travel": I suppose your $P$ is rather some sort of extended object. If so, you just need to rotate $P$ around itself of the same angle $P$ rotates around $O$, and in the same direction, supposing of course that $P$ starts in the right position.

Comment: Hi yes, P is actually a "camera" in an OpenGL scene, appreciate that Points don't really have a direction. Which is why I included my diagram. I will try and do what you suggested. Thank you.